# How to parse xml S3 bucket in python

Tags: amazon-s3

Fail to parse xml from s3 bucket

This is response from S3 bucket:

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Name>example-bucket</Name>
  <Prefix>photos/2006/</Prefix>
  <Marker></Marker>
  <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
  <Delimiter>/</Delimiter>
  <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>

  <CommonPrefixes>
    <Prefix>photos/2006/February/</Prefix>
  </CommonPrefixes>
  <CommonPrefixes>
    <Prefix>photos/2006/January/</Prefix>
  </CommonPrefixes>
</ListBucketResult>
```

When I use this code to parse

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(data)
print root
```

The result is:

```
<Element '{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}ListBucketResult' at 0x7f8f38482110>
```

Result should not container "{http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/}"

Comment: How are you connecting to Amazon S3 to get this XML response? It would be much better to use an SDK to connect with S3.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the string  `xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"` from your `data` variable before parsing it:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data: str = ...  # XML response from a S3 server.

data = data.replace(' xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"', '')
root = ET.fromstring(data)
print(root)
```